# Using nodejs and sockets I'm trying to load the stream together in a loop. Can someone please tell where I'm going wrong?

Tags: node.js, sockets, client

Below is the code,where I'm trying to add image through ajax in socket. But when I run the code this way, all of the data gets appended to the last image even though it is in loop.

```
socket.on('start', function (cou) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cou.length; i++) {
        var image = document.getElementById('cam'+i);
        var divSocket = io(location.origin + 'cam'+i);
        divSocket.on('data', function (data) {
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(data);
            image.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + bytes;
        });
    };
});
```

Can someone please tell where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.js will start to do this loop asynchronously which means it wont wait till it finishes writing, therefore the value of variable i changes. use async loop instead like this:

```
socket.on('start', function (cou) {
    let i = 0;
    async.eachLimit(cou, 1, function(el, done){
        var image = document.getElementById('cam'+i);
        var divSocket = io(location.origin + 'cam'+i);
        divSocket.on('data', function (data) {
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(data);
            image.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + bytes;
        });
        divSocket.on('end', function () {
            i++;
            done();
       });
    };
});
```

take a look at [here](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html)

p.s: I didn't run the code just watch out :)

Comment: How do I load this in Javascript? I get async not defined. I installed the npm package for this. But still not able to run the code.

Comment: Have you installed the right package? it should be installed by this npm install async. Also you can add package to your package.json and install it by npm install .